# How can I find groups nodes sharing common traits in a graph

Tags: graph, neo4j

Lets say I have a graph that relates food items to traits such as sour, sweet, spicy, tangy, ...

How can I query the graph to give me a set of food items matching each possible combination of traits.

i.e.

- all foods that are sweet and spicy
- all foods that are sweet and sour
- all foods that are sweet, sour, and spicy

The graph tuples would look as follows:

```
F1 > Spicy
F1 > Sweet
F2 > Sour
F2 > Sweet
F3 > Sour
...
```

The query should output sets of food matching each possible combination of traits.

```
Spicy => F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
Spicy & Sweet => F1, F3, F5
Spicy & Sweet & Sour => F3
Spicy & Sweet & Sour @ Tangy => F3

Spicy & Sour => ...
Spicy & Sour & Tangy => ...

Spicy & Tangy => ...
```

Comment: So to clarify, traits are nodes, and there is a relation between foods at their traits? So something like (:Food{name:'F1'})-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'Spicy'})?

Answer (score 1):

1) Assume the following inputs:

```
UNWIND [ {name: 'F1', traits: ['Spicy', 'Sweet'                ]},
         {name: 'F2', traits: ['Sour' , 'Sweet'                ]},
         {name: 'F3', traits: ['Tangy', 'Sour', 'Spicy'        ]},
         {name: 'F4', traits: ['Tangy', 'Sour', 'Spice', 'Tart']}  ] AS food
MERGE (F:Food {name: food.name}) WITH F, food
UNWIND food.traits as trait
  MERGE (T:Trait {name: trait})
  MERGE (F)-[:hasTrait]->(T)
RETURN F, T
```

2) Now we need to get all combinations of traits. For this we need [`apoc library`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#bitwise-operations):

```
MATCH (T:Trait) 
WITH collect(T) as traits

// Here we count the number of combinations of traits as a power of two
WITH traits, toInt(round(exp( log(2) * size(traits) )))-1 as combCount

// Go through all the combinations
UNWIND RANGE(1, combCount) as combIndex
 UNWIND RANGE(0, size(traits)-1 ) as p

 // Check whether the trait is present in the combination
 CALL apoc.bitwise.op( toInt(round( exp(log(2) * p) )),'&',combIndex) YIELD value
 WITH combIndex, collect(CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN traits[p] END) as comb

 // Return all combinations of traits
 RETURN comb ORDER BY size(comb)
```

3) Now, for each combination we need to find the intersection for food:

```
MATCH (T:Trait) 
WITH collect(T) as traits

// Here we count the number of combinations of traits as a power of two
WITH traits, toInt(round(exp( log(2) * size(traits) )))-1 as combCount

// Go through all the combinations
UNWIND RANGE(1, combCount) as combIndex
 UNWIND RANGE(0, size(traits)-1 ) as p

 // Check whether the trait is present in the combination
 CALL apoc.bitwise.op( toInt(round( exp(log(2) * p) )),'&',combIndex) YIELD value
 WITH combIndex, collect(CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN traits[p] END) as comb

// Take foods for the first trait:
WITH comb, head(comb) as ft
  OPTIONAL MATCH (ft)<-[:hasTrait]-(F:Food)

// We find the intersection of each food with other traits
WITH comb, collect(F) as testFoods
  UNWIND testFoods as food
    UNWIND comb as trait
      OPTIONAL MATCH p = (food)-[:hasTrait]->(trait)
      WITH comb, food, trait, size(collect(p)) as pairs

      // Check that the number of crossings for food with traits 
      // for each combination of the same number of traits
      WITH comb, food, collect(CASE WHEN pairs > 0 THEN trait END) as pairs
      WITH comb, collect(CASE WHEN size(pairs)=size(comb) THEN food END) as pairs

      // Return combinations where there is a common food
      WITH comb, pairs WHERE size(pairs)>0
RETURN comb, pairs ORDER BY size(comb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the format of neo4j query output is designed for rows with columns, not your desired output format, so this makes things a little tricky.

I would highly recommend just outputting your food items on each row, with boolean columns for membership in each distinct simple trait, then in your application code, insert the food objects into sets for each trait. Then using application logic you can calculate all possible combinations of traits you need, and perform set intersection to generate them.

This would make the neo4j query very easy:

```
MATCH (f:Food)
WITH f
RETURN f.name, EXISTS((f)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'tangy'})) AS tangy,
EXISTS((f)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'sweet'})) AS sweet, 
EXISTS((f)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'sour'})) AS sour, 
EXISTS((f)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'spicy'})) AS spicy
```

That said, if you're determined to do the entire thing with a neo4j query, it's going to be messy, since you'll need to track and generate all the combinations you need yourself. For intersection operations, you'll want to install the [APOC procedures library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_included_procedures_overview).

Seems to me that the best start is to create sets of food nodes according to each individual trait.

```
MATCH (f:Food)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'spicy'})
WITH COLLECT(f) AS spicyFood
MATCH (f:Food)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'sour'})
WITH COLLECT(f) AS sourFood, spicyFood
MATCH (f:Food)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'sweet'})
WITH COLLECT(f) AS sweetFood, sourFood, spicyFood
MATCH (f:Food)-[:IS]->(:Trait{name:'tangy'})
WITH COLLECT(f) AS tangyFood, sweetFood, sourFood, spicyFood
```

Now that you have these, you can do your intersections with every combination you're interested in.

```
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(tangyFood, sweetFood) YIELD value AS tangySweetFood
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(tangyFood, sourFood) YIELD value AS tangySourFood
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(tangyFood, spicyFood) YIELD value AS tangySpicyFood 
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(tangySweetFood, sourFood) YIELD value AS tangySweetSourFood 
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(tangySweetFood, spicyFood) YIELD value AS tangySweetSpicyFood 
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(tangySourFood, spicyFood) YIELD value AS tangySourSpicyFood 
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(tangySweetSourFood, spicyFood) YIELD value AS tangySweetSourSpicyFood 
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(sweetFood, sourFood) YIELD value AS sweetSourFood
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(sweetFood, spicyFood) YIELD value AS sweetSpicyFood
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(sweetSourFood, spicyFood) YIELD value AS sweetSourSpicyFood
CALL apoc.coll.intersection(sourFood, spicyFood) YIELD value AS sourSpicyFood
RETURN tangyFood, sweetFood, sourFood, spicyFood,
tangySweetFood, tangySourFood, tangySpicyFood, 
tangySweetSourFood, tangySweetSpicyFood, tangySourSpicyFood,
tangySweetSourSpicyFood,
sweetSourFood, sweetSpicyFood, 
sweetSourSpicyFood, 
sourSpicyFood
```